# Parse pdf in Net Core

Tags: pdf, asp.net-core, .net-core

I ve a Asp.Net core projet. This project reference another library in which I should extract informations from a  pdf. I was using itextsharp, but it seems not compatible with .net core.

Any idea how I could extract Text from a  pdf file ?

Comment: If you ask the question here, we can make recommendations for 3rd party libraries: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on software recommendations

Comment: @VMAtm It would be better to be able to do it without third party library. If it's the only way I will do it with a library. But my question is not about choosing between separate libs(or "the best lib"). My question is how to do it. Maybe this require a library, I don't know yet.

Comment: @J4N Unless you want to write a PDF parser (and encapsulate the code in your own library), you have to use a 3rd party PDF library.

Comment: I used to use iTextSharp library

Comment: @VMAtm not compatible with .net core

Comment: @J4N historically there was no built-in way to do this. Maybe you can use Microsoft Word for this, as it can open `pdf`, and you can do this programmatically, however, can't say about compatibility.

Comment: @VMatm I don't think there is anything I could do in .Net core to use word.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your own pdf parser, you will need to read up on all the different versions of the pdf file format. They are all officially documented [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html).

Comment: I didn't think it was that complicated. There is so much revisions of differents versions, and the PDF contains 1310 pages, I cannot read all this(nor implement all those versions) isnt there an easiest way? I'm just trying to grab some text from PDF...

Comment: Sorry for the late response but unfortunately, there is no easier way but to use a library already written by someone else. You might be able to write half a parser that would only read the text fields but you would still have to account for the different revisions of the formats. That is unless you are absolutely certain the pdfs that your parser will be reading will all be one exact version. Also, another thing to note is that sometimes text, won't actually be stored as text in the pdf but as an image.

Answer (score 1):

Text extraction from PDF is a complex task. I would not recommend you to do this without a library.

For an Asp.Net Core library I can recommend you [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) (I work for the vendor). The library supports .NET Standard and can be used to extract not only text but paths and images too.

Here are some samples / tutorials:

- [Extract text](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/pdf-text/extract)
- [Extract text by words](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Text/ExtractTextByWords)
- [Extract text, paths and images](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/pdf-text/extract-text-images)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's for a very small open source project that I do on my free time, I can't afford your licences :(

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/VahidN/iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core